# How do I access nested JSON elements in an MQTT message on AWS IoT?

Tags: json, mqtt, aws-iot

The AWS IoT Rule is receiving the following MQTT payload with a topic of 'TempSensors':

`{"message": "{\"sensor\":\"12345\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-01-01 16:00:00\",\"value\":\"[-0.5]\",\"unit\":\"[\"deg. C\"]\"}", "sequence": 1234}`

I'd like to extract the key-value pairs for each element of the "message" so I can pass the following to AWS DynamoDB:

`{"sensor":"12345","timestamp":"2020-01-01 16:00:00","value": -0.5,"unit": "deg. C"}`

I thought I might be able to access the nested elements using dot notation like:

`SELECT message.sensor AS sensorid FROM 'TempSensors'`

but that results in:

`{}`

or maybe grabbing everything using;

`SELECT (SELECT * from message) AS data FROM 'TempSensors'`

which results in:

`{"data":[{"$unknown":"{\"sensor\":\"12345\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-01-01 16:00:00\",\"value\":\"[-0.5]\",\"unit\":\"[\"deg. C\"]\"}"}]}`

or:

`SELECT (SELECT sensor FROM message) AS sensorid FROM 'TempSensors'`

results in:

`{"sensorid":[{}]}`

There must be an easy method for extracting the JSON data that I'm completely missing. What am I not seeing?

Comment: `message` is not a JSON object, it's an escaped string representation of a JSON object. You will need to rein it through a part first

Comment: so I would need to run the JSON string representation through a JSON.parse function?

Answer (score 0):

The payload you received is a string (of a JSON object), you can use `ArduinoJson` library to deserialised it to get the data.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

char payload[] = "{\"message\": {\"sensor\":\"12345\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-01-01 16:00:00\",\"value\":[-0.5],\"unit\":[\"deg. C\"]}, \"sequence\": 1234}";

StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;  // change memory allocation based on your payload message size

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  if (error) {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
    Serial.println(error.c_str());
    return;
  }
  
  // get the sensor info from the deserialised object doc
  const char *sensor = doc["message"]["sensor"];
  double value = doc["message"]["value"][0];
  const char *unit = doc["message"]["unit"][0];
  Serial.printf("Sensor: %s, value: %.1f %s\n", sensor, value, unit);
}

void loop() {

}
```